# Check if only one property is not null or empty among 3 properties

Tags: c#

I have 3 properties (for sake of simplicity 3 variables)
Method `FillOrNotFill` illustrates that strings `a`, `b`, `c` can be empty, not empty or null.

I need to validate a case that only **one string must be not empty and not null**, where the others must be empty or null.

I can do it with multiple conditions (like in those multiple if's), but Im looking for some more elegant solution.

```
string x = "someValue"
string a = FillOrNotFill(x);
string b = FillOrNotFill(x);
string c = FillOrNotFill(x);

//sample of multiple if's
if((!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(payload.a) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(payload.b) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(payload.c)) 
    || (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(payload.b) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(payload.a) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(payload.c)
    || (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(payload.c) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(payload.b) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(payload.a)
    )))
{
    //valid!
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could put them into a colllection, then its easy:

```
string[] all = {a, b, c};
bool result = all.Count(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)) == 1;
```

If there were thousands you could make it more efficient in this way:

```
bool result = all.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)).Take(2).Count() == 1;
```